# cakephp unable to detect model association after manually adding foreign key column to database table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, php-5.3

I have two models in a CakePHP application: Users and Groups. Initially I had not relationships between the two. Now in the database table groups, I manually add the column user_id so that now I have the following relationships between the two:

```
Groups belongsTo Users
Users hasMany Groups
```

Now after doing this for some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
1054: Unknown column 'Group.user_id' in 'field list'
```

I tried to run CakePHP's bake command to see if Cake will automatically detect the relationship between my two models. When I try to bake the User model, CakePHP does not even detect that there is a hasMany relationship between User and Group. Any idea why is this happenning and how I can fix this please?

Thank you

Comment: Try clearing your cache.

Comment: which cache do I need to clear

Comment: In cake 2.x, delete everything inside app/tmp/cache/models/ I'm not sure about Cake 1.3, it might be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding how you want your associations, but I would imagine that:

> A User belongsTo a Group
>
> A Group hasMany Users

Example User model:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Example Group model:

```
class Group extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = 'User';
}
```

Your Users table will need a `group_id` field.

All of this is assuming that you want one group per user. If you want Users to have multiple groups then you may wish to define a HABTM relationship between Users and Groups, or perhaps researching [Access Control Lists](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html) may point you in a better direction (I have yet to utilize Cake's ACL component yet).

Either way, I highly suggest reviewing the Cakebook page on [Associations: Linking Models Together](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).